# AWS X-ray import with Typescript

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, aws-sdk, aws-xray

I currently use postgresql-node in my lambda with

```
import { Client } from 'pg'
```

I want to instrument the Postgresql lib with AWS X-ray. The Nodejs example has this line:

```
var AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
var pg = AWSXRay.capturePostgres(require('pg'));
```

How would I convert the second line in that to proper Typescript. All the variations I come up with produce some errors or warnings. For example I would guess this would work:

```
const pg = AWSXRay.capturePostgres(require('pg'))
```

but not only you get ESlint warning for `require` being used without `import` but after that `pg.Client` says `pg namespace not found`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's slightly ugly but this seems to work:

```
import * as pg from 'pg'
const patchedPg = AWSXRay.capturePostgres(pg)
```

Comment: I have only seen this method.

Comment: The snippet in this answer is correct. Here's the TS [definition](https://github.com/willarmiros/aws-xray-sdk-node/blob/master/packages/postgres/lib/postgres_p.d.ts#L4) where `capturePostgres` is defined - it uses the wildcard import to define `pg`. I'll get that documentation updated.